# Presenting a dialog box according to data sent from portlet

Tags: jsp, dialog, portlet

I'd appreciate your help on this:
I write jsp portlets based on portlet 2.0. I'm trying to implement this scenario:
1) A user fills out a  form and submits it.
2) The user is redirected back to the main jsp and **a dialog box is opened, presenting the serial number of the newly created call**. When the user clicks "OK" the dialog disappears, until another form is submitted.

My application uses plain-old HTML form submissions and the portlet's methods, like doView() and the annotated processAction() methods - not AJAX calls. So, my current implementation is passing the newly created call's serial number as a request attribute. If such an attribute exists, I display a dijit.dialog. The dialog is hidden when the user clicks "OK".

Nevertheless, whenever the user refreshes the page, the attribute is set again and so the dialog is displayed again. I've  tried removing the attribute in many ways, but it keeps coming back...

Is there some way I can pass data from my serverside to my clientside, so that a dialog is opened only once per form submission?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the net shows that there's no way to implement this feature except for cometd.

Thanks,
Gamadon